# WP: How to use ToList() method for select multiple columns statement in linq to sql?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I selected 4 columns from my table by using select statement LINQ to SQL. Then I create a new List to store the query result. BUT, the code **room.ToList();** is WRONG.

1. Why cannot we use "rooms_list = room.ToList()"?
2. How should we do to solve the problem???

Thanks for teaching me!

```
private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> rooms_list = new List<string>();

            using (LVDatabaseEntities database = new LVDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var room = from x in database.PHONGCHOIs
                            select new { x.TENPHONG, x.MATKHAUPHONG, x.CHUPHONG, x.SOLUONG };
                rooms_list = room.ToList();
            }
            MessageBox.Show(rooms_list.Count.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: `the code room.ToList(); is WRONG.` *Why is it wrong?*  You need to [edit] and add details on why your code is failing.  Also `List<string> rooms_list = new List<string>();` you're throwing away an instance.  Change this to `List<string> rooms_list = null;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rooms_list = room.ToList() is wrong, because it is not the List of type string.

To fix this, first create a class for a room

```
class Room
{
  string TENPHONG { get; set; }
  string MATKHAUPHONG { get; set; }
  string CHUPHONG{ get; set; }
  string SOLUONG{ get; set; }
}
```

Then, change your code like this

```
List<Room> rooms_list = new List<Room>();

using (LVDatabaseEntities database = new LVDatabaseEntities())
{
   var rooms = from x in database.PHONGCHOIs
                    select new Room{ 
    TENPHONG = x.TENPHONG,
    MATKHAUPHONG = x.MATKHAUPHONG,
    CHUPHONG = x.CHUPHONG,
    SOLUONG  = x.SOLUONG };
   rooms_list = room.ToList();
}
MessageBox.Show(rooms_list.Count.ToString());
```

*Not tested. Let me know if anything didn't work